# Nesting Rcpp functions

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it possible to nest `Rcpp` functions in each other?
I have a dummy example right here:

```
cppFunction(
  'int add3(int x) {
  return x+3;
}')

cppFunction(
  'int add4(int x) {
  return add3(x)+1;
}')

add3(2)
```

This does not work. How can I make this work?

**Edit:** Okay, so I followed Dirk's advice and now I have a `test.cpp` file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int add3(int x) {
    return x + 3;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int add4(int x) {
    return add3(x)+1;
}
```

Which I load in R with `sourceCpp("test.cpp")`. Now I can use both functions in R and they work although one function calls the other function.

Comment: Nice followup and edit.  Because it shows the duality. These are both standard C++ functions so they can call each other. Yet they both have export tags so they are both callable from R -- for which really only the function signature and tag matters, and not what the function itself does.  R does not know, and does not need to know.  Full C++ power to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to your question get a little technical quickly, but are all provided in the [Rcpp Attributes vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf), and have been for a long time.

First off, you are more-or-less misusing `cppFunction()`.  It is made for *quick and simple one-off function tests*.  Not for writing "infrastructure" or more complex code.  For which you should use `sourceCpp()`, or better still, use a package.

If you switch you code to `sourceCpp()` and the `[[Rcpp::export]]` tag you will notice (in `verbose=TRUE` mode, or in package building) that the exported functions get 'transliterated' into other functions that R calls.

So yes you can nest functions, as you can in C / C++. Nothing is taken from you.  But *you cannot call the inner, nested function from R* but that is possible with the API offered to us by R and which we use (and free you from interfacing directly).  It only has `SEXP .Call(functionanme, SEXP a, SEXP b,...)` as an interface.  I.e. a different signature.

But on the C / C++ you can nest, provided you compile your code differently.

Comment: Thank you, I am quite new to C++ and Rcpp, so I am still a bit lost.

Comment: Well a warm welcome to you then.  There is, sadly, a lot to learn. I have been at C++ since my days as a (under- and grad) student several decades ago.  But we have _a lot_ of Rcpp documentation and examples. A small package `RcppExamples`, the Rcpp Gallery with 100+ posts, ten vignettes, the mailing list, 2800+ questions here ... and of course 2500+ packages on CRAN.  I always recommend the mailing list if only to lurk and absorb. Rather quiet these days.